# How to auto align a table inside a well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following template (used bootstrap and custom css)

```
    <div class="well well1">

            {% for k, m in items %}
                <span>
                    <button class="btn btn-default drop">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mysite['{{ k }}']"> <b>{{ k }}</b>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </span>
                <br><br>

            <table ng-show="mysite['{{ k }}']" class="table table-bordered tbl" ng-cloak>
....
```

CSS

```
.well1 {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The size of the `table` will get increase, because the `th` is actually a variable. When the no of `th` is higher then `table` is becoming un-aligned with its `well`. Is there any way I can fix it? Means no matter how long is my `table`, its always comes under the `well`, also a scroll bar for very long tables inside the `well`? any idea guys?

Comment: It's just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kzu2o446/3/)

Comment: Unless you have this kind of [content](https://jsfiddle.net/kzu2o446/5/)

Comment: If that's the case you just have to add `word-break:break-all;` in your `td`. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kzu2o446/6/)

Comment: Its not the content. The number of `th` is actually growing up

Comment: Number of `th`? You mean the count of `th`?

Comment: Have you tried bootstrap responsive table?

Comment: I can't see `th` tag in your code. If I get it correctly, the count of your `th` is growing up like it is inside a loop? And your table width is expanding. And you can't do anything about it but to use `table-responsive` class in your well. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kzu2o446/9/)